# Gatsby: Inject a field in a graphql query before executing it within a plugin

Tags: node.js, plugins, graphql, gatsby, inject

So my use case seems very simple yet I'm struggling to figure out how can I do it.

In essence, I want to develop a `gatsby-plugin` that modifies all contentful-related graphQL queries to always insert the `contentful_id` so the returned data always contains that field. This way consumers of my plugin won't have to add `contenful_id` field in all of their grapqhQL queries.

Is this even doable? I'm not interested in creating fields as I believe they won't be part of the returned data unless you add that field explicitly.

Comment: Finally figured out how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

The way to do it:

- Use `graphql` SDK to visit the nodes. Define a visitor like this:

```
const { print, visit, parse } = require('graphql');
const visitor = {
    SelectionSet(node, key, parent) {
      if (!isQuery(parent) && !isFragment(parent)) {
        node.selections.push({
          kind: 'Field',
          name: { kind: 'Name', value: 'yourFieldName' },
        });
      }
    },
  };

function isQuery(node) {
  return node.kind === 'OperationDefinition' && node.operation === 'query';
}

function isFragment(node) {
  return node.kind === 'FragmentDefinition';
}
```

- Then you visit and print it back to a string:

```
  const result = visit(parse(queryAST), { enter: visitor });

  return print(result);
```

- Last step is to add the desired field to all nodes (otherwise the field will not exist and your tampered queries won't work). You can achieve this attaching to this event:

```
exports.setFieldsOnGraphQLNodeType = () => {
  return {
    yourFieldName: {
      type: GraphQLString,
      resolve: (source) => {
        return source.contentful_id || '';
      },
    },
  };
};
```